# I want to rasterise a shape file but it is taking me ages to complete and have not succeeded yet. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: r, spatial, rasterizing

I have a shapefile that I made in qgis of a national park with landcover type. I clipped a large shapefile of Thailand with a smaller shapefile of just the park. This file (DPKY.lc5) is now 10.5 Mb. When I run the code it takes forever and has not been successful. Why is that?

```
library(raster)
DPKY.lc5 <- shapefile("dpky.lc5.shp")
DPKY.lc5 <- spTransform(DPKY.lc5, CRS('+init=EPSG:4326'))
DPKY.lc5$VALUE<-as.numeric(DPKY.lc5$VALUE)
rr <- raster(DPKY.lc5, res=0.01)  
rr1 <- rasterize(DPKY.lc5, rr, field="VALUE")   
rr1
```

I would expect this to work as it is only 10.5Mb but it takes forever. I need this raster to work so I can use data points in another data frame to show the frequency of elephant habitat use in the park. I succeeded with other raster files to get elevation and slope aspect but this time it doesn't like​ it.

Comment: I simplified the code, but, as you say, it should run. Without the file it is hard to say more.

Comment: The file is a Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with 878 elements and it is 10.5Mb.